# How can I decode an array of structs that is encoded with arbitrary data?

Tags: solidity, encoding, abiencoderv2

I'm using `calldata` of `abi.encode(123 , arrayOfStructs)` and `abi.decode(data[:32], (uint256))` to get 123. But I'm unable to get the array of structs with `abi.decode(data[32:], (myStruct[]))`

On the other hand, if I use `abi.encode(arrayOfStructs, 123)` I can decode with `abi.decode(data, (myStruct[]))`, but I can't find the 123 anywhere.

Comment: can you post a picture of the code you have/results/errors you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer. When decoding multiple encoded items (including multiple types), you decode with a tuple as the second argument containing the type of each item.

For example with:

```
struct myStruct {
   uint a;
   uint b;
}

myStruct[] memory arrayOfStructs = ....

bytes memory data = abi.encode(123 , arrayOfStructs);
```

There are two items (a uint256 and myStruct[]). You'd decode with:

```
// must specify uint256 if uint
(uint num, myStruct[] _arrayOfStructs) = abi.decode(data, (uint256,myStruct[]));
```